# Как разбить строку по шаблону - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, split

Никак не могу сообразить, как разбить строку на подобии `boxShadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 1px 1px 10px 0px` в массив

```
[0]: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)
[1]: 1px
[2]: 1px
[3]: 10px
[4]: 0px
```

Про метод `.split()` я знаю, но как должен выглядеть разделитель не догадываюсь. Буду благодарен за вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 1px 1px 10px 0px'.split(/(?<!,)\s+/))
```